# C# - structure of 4-bits values

Tags: c#

I have to create a structure which will have a size of 2 bytes. The structure have to contain 4 values and every value should have 4-bits length. How can I do that?

In C I can do something like:

```
typedef struct MyStructure
{
    uint8_t  value1   :4;
    uint8_t  value2   :4;
    uint8_t  value3   :8;
}
```

Comment: Have you made any searching regarding this? Have you tried anything? If so, can you post your findings?

Comment: Here's something that might be of value: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3362736/238902

Comment: You can use `UInt16` and extract the bits.

Comment: @HansKesting: A `BitVector32` would be better.

Comment: @leppie - you are right, [that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.aspx) was the one I meant.

Comment: you can also find some info here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719537/c-sharp-language-changing-the-first-four-bits-in-a-byte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the smallest addressable size of value is byte (8 bits) you can't do that so easily. You can create a type with two `byte` fields and use properties to `get`/`set` them as 4 different values.

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    private byte _ab;
    private byte _cd;

    public byte A
    {
        get { return (byte)(_ab & 15); }
        set { _ab = (byte)((_ab & 240) | (value & 15)); }
    }

    public byte B
    {
        get { return (byte)(_ab >> 4); }
        set { _ab = (byte)((_ab & 15) | (value & 240)); }
    }

    // the same for C and D
}
```

Comment: This is not reliable. Field members might be padded or pointer aligned.

Comment: As long as you don't use two fields as backend for one property it should work. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I believe that value & 240 will give me 0. It should be value << 4

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's already some class for this purpose I'm unaware of, your best bet is probably to use a `UInt16`, as suggested by leppie, then have properties to get and set the "sub-values", transparently performing masking and shifting as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify two bytes and use properties for the bit access

```
public struct X {
    public byte A;
    public byte B;

    public byte A_L {
        get {
            return (byte)(A >> 4);
        }
    }
    public byte A_R {
        get {
            return (byte)(A & 15);
        }
    }
    public byte B_L {
        get {
            return (byte)(B >> 4);
        }
    }
    public byte B_R {
        get {
            return (byte)(B & 15);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use standard `UInt16` type (no *explicit structures* at all):

```
  UInt16 value = ...

  // Get corresponding values:

  Byte value1 = (Byte) (value >> 12);
  Byte value2 = (Byte) ((value >> 8) & 0xF);
  Byte value3 = (Byte) (value & 0xF);

  // Set corresponding values

  UInt16 value = (UInt16) ((value1 << 12) | (value & 0x0FFF));
  UInt16 value = (UInt16) ((value2 << 8) | (value & 0xF0FF));
  UInt16 value = (UInt16) (value3 | (value & 0xFF00));
```

Comment: Won't the size of this be > 2 bytes?

Comment: The structure in the question is of 2 byte size, so I've chosen UInt16 as its representation. You can use int/uint (4 bytes), long/ulong (8 bytes) for "value", just change 1st line to "Byte value1 = (Byte) ((value >> 12) & 0xFF);"